# Anylogic - New Beginner: Action charts How to return visable the variables?

Tags: charts, action, anylogic

I am new to anylogic and need to create an actionchart for my master thesis. I know how to set it up and all but I don't know how I can see if the algorithm worked. I tried to use statistics where I choose my used variables but this shows me always the initial value.

This is what I tried to do: Just a first easy algorithm. I have a variable "test" with initial value 0. I have created an action chart with a "for loop" `(for i=0;i<10;i++)`. And in the loop I have placed a code-block with `test=test+1;`.
And I have placed outside of the loop a return-block where I return "test".
So this action chart should just add 1 for every loop to my variable test. At a result the value should be 10.

When I am running this there are no errors but also no results. The Statistic block only shows the value 0. And now I don't know what I am doing wrong. Is the error in the action chart or at the statistics?

I have searched in Google and read "anylogic in three days" and was searching at the anylogic help.pages... I havn't found a solution so I thought that maybe someone knows what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I rebuilt the example you describe, and I am getting an action chart that returns the value 10.  I also added a statistics block and associated it with the value of test, and it shows a value of 10.  Is it possible that you are just never calling the action chart (analogous to calling a function), therefore it never executes?

[image]

In general, I would avoid action charts, as I have found it is just easier to write and maintain code in the AnyLogic functions or Advanced Java area.

Comment: Good morning Miss Greer, thank you for your comment! I think you are right. I tried to call the action chart via a button but that does also not work. i will look through your answer and try to reproduce your startup properties.

Comment: Edit:Wow! It really worked! Thank you so much. I have also got the button to work. That was exactly what i wanted to do. By the way i think you are right that functions are way better. Also to write this code in java... but saidly my professor wants a result in anylogic where you can graphicaly represent an algorithm. I will talk to him tomorrow and show him some results so maybe he will understand that anylogic is not the greatest tool for my task.

Comment: If your algorithm is simple enough, the action charts may be ok.  The reality is that code is actually better for explaining algorithms to people because of all the extensive comments you can add about how/why the algorithm is doing something.  When I write code, my goal is to write something my mom could read (at least within a single function).  My mom was a 5th grade teacher and has never had a programming class.  I know it is not possible to always hit that goal (sorry mom), but I find giving yourself some perspective on "is this readable to someone else" is important.